# Deriving the distribution of standardized variables with empirical mean and standard deviation

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

I'm working with a set of independent and identically distributed random variables $\{ x_i \}_{i=1}^N$, where each $x_i$ follows a Gaussian distribution $P_X(x) = \mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \sigma^2)$. This notation $\mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \sigma^2)$ represents the Gaussian probability density function (p.d.f.) with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. It's straightforward to show that, by defining $y_i \equiv \frac{x_i - \mu}{\sigma}$, we obtain $y_i \sim P_Y(y) = \mathcal{N}(y; 0, 1)$.

I'm interested in exploring a similar transformation but using empirical estimates of the mean and standard deviation instead:
$$z_i \equiv \frac{x_i - \hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
where $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are the empirical mean and standard deviation, respectively, given by:
$$\hat{\mu} \equiv \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
$$\hat{\sigma^2} \equiv \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (3)$$

**My question is: How can we derive the distribution of $z_i$ for a given fixed $N$?**.

It's important to note the differences from the initial example:

- Unlike $\mu$ and $\sigma$, which are constants, $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are random variables dependent on the set ${ x_i }_{i=1}^N$.
- Both $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$ are functions of the $x_i$'s.
- The distribution of $z_i$ is generally not normal. For instance, with $N=2$, any two distinct $x_1, x_2$ will be mapped to $z_i \in \{ -1, +1 \}$, resulting in a distribution for $z_i$ of $P_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2} \delta(z-1) + \frac{1}{2} \delta(z+1)$.

Comment: I believe that you are precisely sampling a uniform point on the intersection of the unit sphere with the plane $x_1+\ldots+x_N=0$.

Comment: That is, the sphere of radius $\sqrt N$

Comment: Do you want to find the distribution of each $z_i$ or the joint distribution of $(z_,1,\dots,z_N)$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis is it even possible to get the joint distribution of $(z_1, \dots, z_N)$? Eq.(1) seems to be a non invertible transformation (i.e. null Jacobian)

Comment: @user1172131 : This depends on what you mean by "to get the joint distribution". The joint distribution is a measure. In what terms do you want to describe it? For instance, it could be described in terms of the joint pdf of $z_1,\dots,z_{N-1}$. You still have not answered my previous question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm interested in the p.d.f. of $z_i$, i.e. the joint distribution marginalized over the $z_j$ , $j \neq i$

Comment: "the joint distribution marginalized over the $z_j$, $j\ne i$" ... The joint distribution of what random variable**s**? What could "marginalized over the $z_j$, $j\ne i$" possibly mean? Also, again, in what terms do you want to describe the distribution you are interested in? Here, you may want to say: the pdf of $z_i$, for **each** $i$ --which is, by symmetry, the same as the pdf of $z_1$. Or you may want to say: the joint pdf of $z_1,\dots,z_{N-1}$. Or something else -- expressed in standard, common terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony's comment has the correct answer: $Z=(z_1,\ldots ,z_N)$ is uniformly distributed on $\|Z\|^2=N$, $\langle e, Z\rangle=0$, $e=(1,1,\ldots, 1)$ (that is, the joint distribution is the $(N-2)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to this set and normalized).

As $Z$ is obviously supported by this set, this follows from the fact that the distribution is invariant under rotations $R\in O(n)$ with $Re=e$ and under $Z\mapsto -Z$. To see this, recall that $Y=RX$ has the same joint distribution as $X$. See [here.](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mvn-ltt.html)

Moreover,
$$
N\overline{Y}=\langle e, Y\rangle =\langle e, RX\rangle = \langle R^te, X\rangle = \langle e, X\rangle = N\overline{X}
$$
and similarly $NS_Y^2=\|Y-\overline{Y}e\|^2=\|R(X-\overline{X}e)\|^2=NS_X^2$. Thus
$$
RZ = \frac{1}{S_X}R(X-\overline{X}e) = \frac{1}{S_Y}(Y-\overline{Y}e) ,
$$
and indeed $Z$ and $RZ$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you @Christian Remling for your answer; what would be then the explicit of the p.d.f.?

Comment: @user1172131: This will not be very simple in terms of the original variables. The intersection of the sphere with a hyperplane through the origin in another sphere of dimension one lower, so in suitable coordinates, you are dealing with the surface measure of a sphere.